# In Google Sheets - find word within cell, return cell without word

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a google sheet with a column of item names, (i.e. "Amy dress, Brooke Tshirt, etc.) Some of these items have a prefix - JK or JL (JK - Amy Dress, JL - Brooke Dress) in addition to the non-prefixed versions. I'm trying to find a way to search for a prefix (JK - ) and return the item name associated with that prefix in a different column.

Search for "JK - ", find JK - Amy Dress, return Amy Dress. Please help!

Tried lookup and match, but this is too complicated for my skill set.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use a Google Sheets Query.
If you want something like this:
[image]

Based on the table above the query you'll have to use will be:

```
=query(A:B;"select * where B Starts with 'JK'";-1)
```

If you want to select only the B column just remove the A:

```
=query(B;"select * where B Starts with 'JK'";-1)
```

The query automatically creates a new "table" with all the values you need.

If you want to make it customizable use the following query:

```
=query(A:B;"select * where B Starts with '"&$G1&"'";-1)
```

In this case instead of "JK" we are searching something that starts with the content of the cell G1. So if you type JK in the G1 cell you will obtain the same result as before.

Hope it helps.